# Where is my code syntactically incorrect?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Declare variable  
    ifstream inFile;
// Declare constant 
    const int MAX = 600;
// Declare an array of strings named name that holds up to MAX 
    string name[MAX] = {};
// Declare an array of whole numbers named grade that holds up to MAX
    double grade[MAX] = {};
// Declare variables quantity, x, avg, and sum (initialized to zero) that hold whole numbers 
    int sum = 0, avg, x, quantity;
// Open input file
    inFile.open("indata3.txt");
// Check if the file was opened
    if (!inFile)
    {
    cout << "File was not found!" << endl;
    return 1;
    }
// Set x to 0 
    x = 0;
// Read name and grade from the file and assign them to name[x] and grade[x] 
    inFile >> name[x];
    inFile >> grade[x];
// While (not-end-of-file) 
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
//Increment x 
    x++;
//  Read a name and a grade from the file and assign them to name[x] and grade[x] 
    inFile >> name[x];
    inFile >> grade[x];
    }
// Print message 
    cout << "Enter quantity of grades to be processed (0-" << x << "): " << endl;
// Read a value from the keyboard and assign it to quantity 
    cin >> quantity;
// For (x = 0 to quantity-1)
    for (x = 0; x <= quantity-1)
    {
// Accumulate grade[x] in sum 
    grade[x]+=sum;
    }
// Assign to avg the value returned by average (sum, quantity)
    avg = sum/quantity;
// Print "Average grade: ", avg 
    cout << "Average grade: " << avg << endl;
// Print "Name", "Grade", "   Comment" 
    cout << "Name" << "," << "Grade" << "," << "   Comment"  << endl;
// For (x = 0 to quantity-1) 
    for (x = 0; x <= quantity-1)
{
// Print name[x], grade[x]
    cout << name[x] << ", " << grade[x] << endl;
// If (grade[x] < avg) 
    if (grade[x] < avg)
    {
//  Print "   below average"
    cout << "   below average" << endl;
    }
// Else if (grade[x] > avg) 
    else if (grade[x] > avg)
    {
//  Print "   above average"
    cout << "   above average" << endl;
    }
// Else
    else()
    {
//  Print "   average"
    cout << "   average" << endl;
    }
}
// Close the file.
    inFile.close();

return 0;
}
```

I believe my code is fine but I have 4 syntax errors that include the following:

```
.cpp(49) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
.cpp(61) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
.cpp(78) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
.cpp(79) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

The problem could be with how the for loops are nested but I am not too sure exactly where exactly to fix it since I've already played around with it a bit. Any help would be great thanks! Also warning you that I'm a noob so sorry for the ugly code.

Comment: You can use the free AStyle program to format the code. Many editors also have that as built-in functionality. Unfortunately it's well hidden in Visual Studio.

Comment: `for (x = 0; x <= quantity-1)`  Do you see something wrong with this?

Comment: `else()` is just going to confuse anyone who reads your code...

Comment: @Nora: Don't "fix" the code in your questions. It renders any answers irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler is complaining that you have syntax errors? Most likely it's because you have syntax errors ....

---

```
for (a; b; c) {
           |  For loop has 3 parts...
```

---

```
else() // It should be else {
     | else cannot have a condition, let alone an empty one
```

Read your compiler errors and fix what it says.

http://ideone.com/3ZJjaO - Compiler Errors

http://ideone.com/kMCKIV - Compiler Errors Fixed

*Note: You have some work ahead of you, you have a series of infinite looooooooops as well as other problems. Might be worth picking up a c book and trying all the examples.*

Comment: Does this question qualify for a RTFM moment?